# Interrupt Signal Ignored On Command Line

Tags: macos, unix, zsh, macos-ventura

Quite a few commands from OSX ignore SIGINT from CTRL + C, while SIGQUIT from CTRL + \ does the job.

The zsh(1) key-binding `intr` looks correct by default. Is SIGINT deprecated in some way? I believe this used to work on previous releases.

```
% stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 30 rows; 113 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
% which iostat
/usr/sbin/iostat
% iostat 1
              disk0               disk4       cpu    load average
    KB/t  tps  MB/s     KB/t  tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
   20.69   32  0.66    32.81  210  6.74   3  2 96  1.10 1.33 1.36
   15.33   12  0.18    36.94  301 10.87  15  4 81  1.10 1.33 1.36
   16.00   20  0.31    23.12  289  6.53   7  2 90  1.10 1.33 1.36
^C    0.00    0  0.00     7.86  205  1.57   2  1 97  1.09 1.32 1.36
    0.00    0  0.00     7.61  197  1.46   1  1 98  1.09 1.32 1.36
    0.00    0  0.00     8.11  179  1.42   1  1 98  1.09 1.32 1.36
    0.00    0  0.00     7.54  183  1.35   1  1 98  1.09 1.32 1.36
^\zsh: quit       iostat 1
%
```

Comment: Adding details which commands are affected by the problem might help.

Comment: How about the iostat(1) example given @Bodo?

Comment: Does `kill -2 pid_of_command` work?

Comment: Is this the only command? With a few examples of commands affected or not affected by the problem, it might be possible to see a pattern or some common ground.

Comment: @PascaldeKloe try `iostat 1 &; sleep 5; pkill -INT iostat` to make it a bit more clear where sigint is ignored

Comment: Good call @yvs2014. An `iostat 5 > /dev/null &; kill -INT %1` gets `[1]  + interrupt  iostat 5 > /dev/null` so the signal itself works as a command termination. 

Comment: Interactive commands like top(1) ignore CTRL + C, yet find(1), grep(1), make(1) and cat(1) terminate.

Comment: @PascaldeKloe  what if you try to interrupt 'iostat' which runs watching only one disk (for example disk0), or pressing ctrl-c a couple times? those zeros just after ^C in the output above looks a bit unexpected

Comment: Now all commands terminate nicely with CTRL + C, including iostat(1) and top(1).  I have no explaination. Multiple tries did not help the other day @yvs2014—tried that too.

Comment: And there it is again. Multiple signals including long delays have no effect. https://gist.github.com/pascaldekloe/5397ba482f6648b9692598f6ce47a7d9 Looks like a bug rather than a knowledge question now. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug happening at random, and *only* when vi(1) is in the background. Closing vi(1) after an ignored interrupt does not resolve the issue. A shell restart is required to reset to normal once the issue appears.

```
% vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jun 23 2023 22:12:29)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-1544
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

Full log available at https://gist.github.com/pascaldekloe/5397ba482f6648b9692598f6ce47a7d9.